# How do you switch an Azure Web App's continuous deployment repository?

Tags: git, azure

I setup continuous deployment with a local git repository for an Azure Web App and have pushed several updates to it. I disconnected from the repository so I could setup a new one, as per the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#disable-continuous-deployment). When I setup a new continuous deployment with a local git repository my original repository is still there with all the updates I pushed, and when I try pushing to it from my new source, git tells me I can't because the versions aren't merged properly:

> error: failed to push some refs to < my url >
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I also tried deleting the repository remotely using:

```
git push azure :master
```

but was denied:

> remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion. You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the current branch, with or without a warning message. To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'. refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master To < my-url >
>    ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
>   error: failed to push some refs to '< my-url >'

Is disconnecting from the source like I did not supposed to remove the repository so a new one can be added? When I go into Kudu before or after disconnecting the site and repository is still there.

I'm not very familiar with Kudu yet, but tried deleting the .git directory using the browser UI function to see what would happen but it doesn't get deleted. I tried running `git status` in the console after navigating to the repository directory, but it tells me:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I'm not sure what to do if disconnecting doesn't work, it doesn't let me delete it remotely, and don't seem to have any control using Kudu.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete .git using the command line in Kudu:

`rm -rf site/repository/.git`

Comment: Nice! I was able to do this in the Azure web interface by going to *Development Tools* > *SSH*